# C++ std::variant - Type traits to verify that the contained variant types meet some assumptions

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, type-traits

Let's say I have some set of types that all have a common parent:

```
struct some_tag;

struct A : some_tag;
struct B : some_tag;
struct C : some_tag;
struct D : some_tag;
```

Individually, one can test whether a type is a child of `some_tag` with:

```
template <typename T>
using has_some_tag = std::is_base_of<some_tag, T>;
```

But, let's say I have some variants which could accept any number and any combination of these types, such as:

```
using variant_1 = std::variant<A,B,C>;
using variant_2 = std::variant<B,C>;
using variant_3 = std::variant<D,A>;
...
```

And then, let's say I'm using these variant types to pass in as a template parameter to some class that has visitation logic to deal with each of the types.

```
template <typename V>
struct some_other_type;
```

For type `V`, I'd like to have static_assertions in place that it meets the following criteria:

1. `V` is a variant
2. `V` is a variant that ONLY accepts types that inherit from `some_tag`.

I think I have all the small pieces together, but I can't work out the best way to inspect variant type.

I think what I need is a trait that would effectively assert that a particular trait holds for each underlying types. I should point out that the ONLY assumption one can make here is `V` should only contain things that inherit from `some_tag`, but we can't make assumptions about the ordering or number of the things that this entails.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did you have a look in a metaprogramming library? I think with boost::mp11, variant is a usual sequence of types that mp_all_of can be run against.

Comment: @smitsyn Unfortunately using boost::mp11 is out of the question for this code base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use partial specialization:

```
template<class>
struct checker : std::false_type {};

template<class... Ts> 
struct checker<std::variant<Ts...>> : 
    std::bool_constant<(has_some_tag<Ts>::value && ...)> {};
```

and then write:

```
template<typename V>
struct some_other_type {
    static_assert(checker<V>::value);
};
```

Alternatively, you can employ `std::conjunction` instead of an `&&` fold:

```
template<class... Ts> 
struct checker<std::variant<Ts...>> : std::conjunction<has_some_tag<Ts>...> {};
```

**Edit.** `std::integral_constant<bool>` was replaced with `std::bool_constant`. Thanks, **max66**.

Comment: Awesome! I will try this! Thank you.

Comment: A little simplification: you can use `std::bool_constant<value>` (introduced from C++17, but if you check a `std::variant`, you're using C++17) instead of `std::integral_constant<bool, value>`